# Prove the existence of two constant to bound a function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a continous function, such as exists $p\in\mathbb{R}^+$, $p>1$ verifying:
$$\liminf_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{|x|^p}=L\in(0,+\infty]$$

Prove the existence of two constants, $r,m\in\mathbb{R}^+$ for which $f$ verifies:

$$f(x)\geq mx^p \;\;\;\; \;\; \forall x > r$$

Any hints about how to approach this exercise?

Comment: This does not make sense. What is $t$ here?

Comment: Sorry, that was from other part of the exercise I have already done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $m \in (0,L)$ we have $lim \inf \frac {f{(x)}} {|x|^{p}} >m$. This implies there exist $r$ such that $f(x) >mx^{p}$ for all $x \geq r$.

Comment: Mm, this reasoning would be correct if $L=+\infty$?

Comment: @AntonioGamizDelgado Yes it is correct. In this case $m$ is just any positive number.